# My Firebase Observers will not stop Observing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

In my:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

I create my Firebase observers as such:

```
poolsRef.child(pID).child("lock").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

boxesRef.child(pID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

coordRef.child(pID).child("x").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

coordRef.child(pID).child("y").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

poolsRef.child(pID).child("Winner").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

playersRef.child("pID").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

then in

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
```

I call the removeAllObservers:

```
coordRef.removeAllObservers()

poolsRef.removeAllObservers()

boxesRef.removeAllObservers()

playersRef.removeAllObservers()
```

The problem is when I leave the view where all the observers were created and even thought the removeAllObservers() is called in the `viewDidDisappear` I am no a different view altogether and if I go to the Firebase directly and make a change in regards to data that was related to the observers mentioned above, I can see that the app is still listening when it shouldn't!?

How do I resolve this issue!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From  [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

> Calling removeObserverWithHandle or removeAllObservers on a listener does not automatically remove listeners registered on its child nodes; you must also keep track of those references or handles to remove them.

```
poolsRef.child(pID).child("lock").removeAllObservers()
poolsRef.child(pID).child("Winner").removeAllObservers()
```

and so on with other observers

Comment: I do not need to do anything with `observeSingleEvent` correct?! Same with writes to Firebase... I just want to make sure at this point!

Comment: `observeSingleEvent ` listens only once but `observe` listens until you remove the observer